# Is the location of the strake ( chines) on the two seat F-16 variant is the same as for the one seat one?

Tags: aircraft-design, f-16

Is the location/length of the chines (the cobra hood looking) on the two seat F-16 variant the same as the ones on the single seat variant?

The two seat variant has a *longer cabin*, so it must be further until they meet the wing roots. Is the location of the vortices the same? To me they appear to be more forward on the single seat variant.

Comment: The premise of the question is wrong. The single seat and two seat variants of the F-16 are the exact same length. Other than that, it is not really clear what you are asking

Comment: I asked if the starting point and the end point of these vortex generators  are different one  from  another in single seat and two seat variant of the F16.If not how they influence the vortices at the roots of the wings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  The location of the chines occupy the same fuselage station coordinates on both single and dual seat versions of the F-16.  The addition of a second crew members station in the aircraft necessitates the removal of a forward fuel tank, reducing the total internal fuel capacity of two seat F-16s.